# Does this job offer and link business' bank account sound like a scam?

Tags: scams

I'm broke. I'm looking for a job. I find a guy offering me a job on reddit doing crypto transfers. I don't really know how they make money just trading crypto, but apparently that's the job. Now he wants me to add his business bank account as an external transfer so I can pull money out of it to do the crypto transfers. I don't know anything else about the job or the business he has so I don't know if I can trust him. It's like an underthetable unofficial job, no contracts, nothing.

Does it sound like a scam? Is there some way I can validate the bank account info he gives me?

Well I cut contact and called him a scammer, here's what he said to me:

> "Man you need to relax your paranoia Crypto mining isn’t illegal Look
> up OSCP if you want. I work freelance What would I scam you off? I
> never asked for your money I literally made you an offer You can
> choose not to work with me but don’t accuse with all this shit You
> clearly have some issues to work on, sort yourself out. Goodluck"

Here's his reddit user: https://www.reddit.com/user/Temporary_Potato_484

He told me his company's name was "Core inc"

**Update 1 - 7/21**

Holy sh** this goes so much deeper than I originally thought.

I called him a scammer. And I said "call me then, you won't". And he did. He told me to "hold on" for 5 minutes before he joined the call.

We hopped on to a call (on discord). He said he didn't want to be disrespected by me calling him a scammer. He paused several times, probably talking to the people around him. He's using some sort of voice filter and has a heavy accent, but I can't tell what accent it is, his voice is very deep.

I couldn't understand anything except that he wants to send me an ID to show that he's legit, and that I should send him my ID so we can confirm a business deal. We leave the call.

Now he's telling me that he'll straight up send money to my PayPal and that's all I have to give to him.

I said, "before I give you my paypal, I want to see your ID as you promised". Now he said "hold on" again for 30 minutes. and that's where I am at now.

I'll post updates here regularly until this is over. I saved the chat logs too if anyone wants to see them let me know.

Comment: This is a scam. Stop talking to this person immediately.

Comment: This does indeed sound like a scam - there is no way that a job like this is going to be legitimate.

Comment: Thanks. I'll ask him for his companies' name then and see what happens. I'll post an update when he replies.

Comment: "I'm broke. I'm looking for a job."  Legitimate employers are *begging* for people who'll show up to work every day.

Comment: A 34 karma Reddit whose main posts are in the personal finance, poverty finance, and credit subreddits and most posts are hinting at "job opportunities" or "what if you could pay that debt off"? Its a scammer with a fresh account trolling for financially illiterate people to scam.

Comment: Be really careful dealing with them.  They are clearly scammers, and are professionals at this.  They are trying to get some valuable information from you.  At the very least, check the [scam baiting tips here](https://www.419eater.com/html/baiting.htm).

Comment: Your initial question was "is this a scam?". It's pretty clear the answer is yes. I'm not sure what else you're hoping to get from this.

Comment: The ID he's promising to send you will be fake - or stolen - and once you send him *your* ID, it'll be added to the pile to use on other marks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even if he gives you the name of a genuine company, it's still a scam.  I can give you the names of any number of companies.  It doesn't mean I really work for them.

At best it's money laundering.  At worst, they are going to rip you off by sending you payments that will bounce, but only *after* you have sent all the money overseas.

Or maybe you will end upgiving them all your bank details, and enough personal information that they can raid your account.

Comment: well I suppose raiding my account won't really do much, I only have $15.94 in my account. but thank you for the answer.

Comment: I’m, not sure money laundering is “at best”, since most likely the bank account he’s trying to get you to pull money out of it not owned by him. That gets you criminal charges. Think about it- why would a legitimate person not just send you the money themselves rather than making g you pull it from them? The only reason for that is because he doesn’t want his fingerprints anywhere near it.

Comment: Any supposed employer who asks you to accept payments that you are not fully entitled to is trying to scam you. There is no reason you should *ever* use a personal account to hold your employer's money.

Comment: @DoctorReality The amount currently in your account is irrelevant, it could even be zero.  Look up "advanced fee scams."  He'll send you money and get you to withdraw it and send a portion elsewhere, then the check will bounce and your account goes negative, with no way to reclaim the money you sent off.